# How to call script on every AWS ElasticBeanstalk change attempt

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, lets-encrypt, certbot

I have `container_command` that will call `certbot` and change my `Nginx` configuration.

In addition, I use AWS `CodePipeline`, which is calling such a script every time master is updated.

But the problem is, `cfn-init.log` is not showing anything when I change EB manually (add environment variable). But it does trigger rebuilding, and drop `nginx.conf` changes made by `certbot`.

How to run the script every time?

I used this [approach](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-container-commands) and changed it to `container_command` (without `leader_only`)

Both don't trigger script upon EB conf changes.

Comment: "when I change EB manually" you shouldn't be doing this, especially since you have CICD pipeline for EB. Why not updated EB env variables to CICD pipeline as well?

Comment: Good question. Have no idea. Will see how to do it properly.

Comment: @Marcin could you please share the name of a service to handle this secret env transitions properly? Thanks

Comment: You can set env variables for EB programmatically using [aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-general.html#command-options-general-elasticbeanstalkapplicationenvironment).